# Prevent random port number in VS2022 .net Core API build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a .net Core 6 API via Visual Studio 2022. It works, everything functions, it launches and Swagger shows my API working across the board. My other local application can access the API endpoints as intended.

Sometimes, when I hit `F5`, this application launches - successfully and fully functional - at a different port, mostly after a machine restart. This creates the issue of my other application not being able to find it and having to be constantly reconfigured, which is annoying and nonsensical.

However, absolutely nothing I do seems to have any impact on it.

I've been through many, many things trying to find a solution.

My VS-generated `Program.cs` file looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddXXX();
//...bunch of those
var app = builder.Build();
app.XXX()
//...bunch of those
app.Run();
```

This pattern does not match any other question, answer, or even most tutorials I can find. I'm thinking this is likely a new pattern for .net Core 6.

Neither `builder`, `builder.Services`, nor `app` contains a method `UseUrl()` or anything that looks even remotely URL related.

The term `IHostBuilder` does not appear anywhere in the application, so any solutions involving that have me lost.

The term "Host" does not appear in `Program.cs` at all.

`appsettings.json` does not have a "Urls" property. Adding it doesn't do anything. Whatever is supposed to be using it must not exist in this context.

The port number (49153 in my case) does not appear anywhere in the project.

`launchsettings.json` has an applicationUrl specified. It's for a port number I've never seen used. Changing it has no effect. Adding "ASPNETCORE_URLS" to the "environmentVariables" has no effect. Changing the Docker "launchUrl" in this file does change which URL is opened in the browser by default, but that URL is then not found.

I have only a mild understanding of Docker and I'm unsure if that would affect the server port, but nothing in `Dockerfile` appears to have any port number set or referenced.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, after you created the web api application inside your VS, it will generated the lanchsettings.json file. Inside this file, it contains the IIS express settings and the application's profile settings.  I suggest you could re-check the lunchsettings.json to make sure you have set the right url and port and try again.

The generated json like below, you will find it contains two applicationUrl, one is for IIS express and another is for application name `CoreSixWebAPI`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:37519",
      "sslPort": 44356
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "CoreSixWebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7169;http://localhost:5169",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you select to use IIS express to run your web api like below image shows, you will find it will use IIS express setting's application url like below, same as the application name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah I usually just hit "F5"... my build is using Docker, so I guess I should learn more about that and check there?